# How to synchronize fields between two different sobjects?

Tags: apex, administration

I need to Synchronize the fields between two different sObjects which are not related to each other.

Let's say I have Object X and Object Y. If I create a field in Object X it has to be created in Object Y and Vice versa.

Can anyone help me out on this thing?

Thanks,
Naveen

Comment: You can't just "synchronize fields" like that. That's not how salesforce works.

Comment: Well, I don't think this is a good approach for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Naveen you can use a trigger for this process.

Comment: Yes Anu, to synchronize records we could to for trigger..but i need Sync fields right? Can we go with trigger for this? I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

These is **no** direct way in creating fields in Salesforce at least by configuration.

But you can use Metadata API and Tooling API. You can create a utility in Apex which will create field in Object using those APIs. This utility would need to be run via scheduled batch. It would be running on frequency at which you create fields.